# Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.

Tags: vb.net

I'm making a program that will remove the pain of hex editing an old DOS game (sensible world of soccer).

The program removes the limit of the number of players you can purchase (5), removes the maximum number of seasons you can compete for (20).

I'm trying to make it so you can edit your transfer budget too but i'm getting a `Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.` error when i run the code select the 50million option.

Here is the full code for my program (the transfer limit & maximum season limit both work):

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Swos_Editor_2013

    Dim transferbudget As String

    Private Sub OpenToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles OpenToolStripMenuItem.Click
    '#########
    '#WARNING#
    '#########
    'Dim answer As DialogResult
    'answer = MessageBox.Show("Make a Backup of your career file then click OK to proceed.  I take no responsibility for damaged career files",
    '                             "*PLEASE READ BEFORE PROCEEDING*", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk)


    '##########################
    '#Progress bar set options#
    '##########################
    ProgressBar1.Minimum = 0
    ProgressBar1.Maximum = 2
    ProgressBar1.Value = 0


    '##################
    '#tool tip options#
    '##################
    Dim toolTip1 As New ToolTip


    toolTip1.AutoPopDelay = 5000
    toolTip1.InitialDelay = 1000
    toolTip1.ReshowDelay = 500
    ToolTip1.ShowAlways = True


    '###################################
    '#Open Swos career file for editing#
    '###################################
    Me.OpenFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:\"
    Me.OpenFileDialog1.Title = "Select Career File for editing"
    Me.OpenFileDialog1.DefaultExt = "*.car"
    Me.OpenFileDialog1.FileName = ""
    Me.OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "Career File(*.car)|*.car"
    Me.OpenFileDialog1.Multiselect = False


    '###################
    '#OK button pressed#
    '###################
    If Me.OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then


        '##############################
        '#increase progress bar to 50%#
        '##############################


        If ProgressBar1.Value < ProgressBar1.Maximum Then
            ProgressBar1.Value += 1
        End If


        '################
        '#Enable buttons#
        '################


        btn_save.Enabled = True
        btn_trans_limit.Enabled = True
        btn_career_limit.Enabled = True
        cb_combo.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub
'#######################
'#Enable combo box drop#
'#######################
Private Sub cb_combo_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cb_combo.CheckedChanged
    ComboBox1.Enabled = True
End Sub
'########################
'#Select Transfer Budget#
'########################
Private Sub ComboBox1_DropDownClosed(ByVal sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.DropDownClosed


    Select Case ComboBox1.SelectedItem
        Case Is = "-£10 million (are you crazy CHALLENGE)"
            transferbudget = "100"
        Case Is = "-£2 million (mid level CHALLENGE)"
            transferbudget = "200"
        Case Is = "-£500k (lower league CHALLENGE)"
            transferbudget = "500"
        Case Is = "£500k (tough)"
            transferbudget = "05"
        Case Is = "£5 million"
            transferbudget = "5"
        Case Is = "£10 million"
            transferbudget = "10"
        Case Is = "£25 million"
            transferbudget = "25"
        Case Is = "£50 million"
            transferbudget = "50000000"
        Case Is = "£99 million"
            transferbudget = "999"                        
    End Select
End Sub
'#######################################
'#exit if EXIT is clicked from dropdown#
'#######################################
Private Sub ExitToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ExitToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub
'#######################
'#Not got a bloody clue#
'#######################
Private Shared Function InlineAssignHelper(Of T)(ByRef target As T, value As T) As T
    target = value
    Return value
End Function
'##################################################################
'#Apply changes made to drop down box AND radio button IF selected#
'##################################################################
Public Sub SaveChanges()
    Dim amount As Integer
    Dim fpath As String = OpenFileDialog1.FileName


    Using stream = New FileStream(fpath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite)
        Dim result As Integer = 0
        Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(3) {}


        stream.Position = 54748
        If (stream.Read(buffer, 0, 4) <> 4) Then
            Throw New Exception(("Didn't read 4 bytes when it should have: " _
                            + (result + "bytes read")))
        End If


        stream.Position = &HD5DC


        buffer = BitConverter.GetBytes(amount)


        stream.Write(buffer, 0, 4)
        stream.Position = &HD880
        If btn_career_limit.Checked Then
            stream.WriteByte(0)
        Else
            stream.WriteByte(1)
        End If


        stream.Position = &HD5C4
        If btn_trans_limit.Checked Then
            stream.WriteByte(&HFF)
        Else
            stream.WriteByte(0)
        End If


        'stream.Write(buffer, 0, 4)
        'stream.Position = &HD5DC
        'If testbutton.Checked Then
        '    stream.WriteByte("3B9AC9FF")
        'End If


        **If cb_combo.Checked = True Then
            stream.Position = &HD5DC
            stream.WriteByte(transferbudget)  ######this is where i get the overflow error#####**
        End If
    End Using
End Sub
'###############################################
'#Save above changes & set progress bar to 100%#
'###############################################


Private Sub btn_save_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_save.Click
    SaveChanges()


    If ProgressBar1.Value < ProgressBar1.Maximum Then
        ProgressBar1.Value += 1
    End If
End Sub
'#########################################################################################################################################
'#                                                              TOOL TIP (MOUSE HOVER)                                                   #
'#                                                                                                                                       #
Private Sub btn_trans_limit_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_trans_limit.MouseHover
    '#
    ToolTip1.SetToolTip(btn_trans_limit, "Removes 5 player transfer limit")                                                             '#
End Sub
Private Sub btn_career_limit_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_career_limit.MouseHover                       '#
    '#                                                                                                                                  '#
    ToolTip1.SetToolTip(btn_career_limit, "Removes 20 season limit")                                                                    '#
End Sub
Private Sub ComboBox1_MouseHover(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.MouseHover                                         '#
    '#                                                                                                                                  '#
    ToolTip1.SetToolTip(ComboBox1, "Select Transfer Budget")                                                                            '#
End Sub
Private Sub btn_save_MouseHover(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_save.MouseHover                                           '#
    '#                                                                                                                                  '#
    ToolTip1.SetToolTip(btn_save, "Save changes to your career file")
End Sub
Private Sub cb_combo_MouseHover(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cb_combo.MouseHover                                           '#
    '#                                                                                                                                  '#
    ToolTip1.SetToolTip(cb_combo, "tick if you want to edit transfer budget")                                                           '#
End Sub

'#########################################################################################################################################
End Class
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not going all this code to maybe find the problem. Did you pinpoint where the problem arises? Just dumping code (especially a "full program") and "it doesn't work" is not really the spirit here.

Comment: sorry the code falls over here:          **If cb_combo.Checked = True Then
            stream.Position = &HD5DC
            stream.WriteByte(transferbudget) **
        End If

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a `String` (`transferbudget`) into the `FileStream.WriteByte` method.  The `WriteByte` method takes a `Byte`, not a `String`.  If you had `Option Strict On`, as you should, this would result in a compile error.  However, since you have `Option Strict Off`, it allows you to compile and just automatically inserts the type conversion from `String` to `Byte` for you.  The type conversion operation will throw an overflow exception if the value in the string is outside of the minimum and maximum value of a `Byte` (0 - 255).  Here's the code where you set the `transferbudget` variable:

```
Select Case ComboBox1.SelectedItem
    Case Is = "-£10 million (are you crazy CHALLENGE)"
        transferbudget = "100"
    Case Is = "-£2 million (mid level CHALLENGE)"
        transferbudget = "200"
    Case Is = "-£500k (lower league CHALLENGE)"
        transferbudget = "500"  'GAH!
    Case Is = "£500k (tough)"
        transferbudget = "05"
    Case Is = "£5 million"
        transferbudget = "5"
    Case Is = "£10 million"
        transferbudget = "10"
    Case Is = "£25 million"
        transferbudget = "25"
    Case Is = "£50 million"
        transferbudget = "50000000"  'GAH!
    Case Is = "£99 million"
        transferbudget = "999"  'GAH!            
End Select
```

As you can see, there are several values there that are greater than 255.

Comment: Initially i had the hex values in those "" positions but then i changed them to the actual value (e.g 10mil was "10000000") but it still fell over, so i started making changes just to the 50mil option to test then i was going to change them all (to save me time).  I've tried changing it from a string to an integer and that doesn't work either.  your post was very helpful tho.  thank you.

Comment: It doesn't matter what type of variable you store them in initially.  The problem is that in the end you are trying to output the entire value as a single byte.  As long as the value is too large for a byte, the conversion will always fail, regardless of the initial variable type.  Check out the `BinaryWriter` class for methods to output multi-byte integers to a stream.

Comment: @lordofdogtown83 - Note: This error would have been flagged up if you have switched Option Strict On. You should do this now: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/08/option-strict-and-option-explicit-in-vbnet-2005.html

Comment: i've scrapped the middle code now that deals with the transferbudget.  i'll have to figure out how to re-write it.